# Spotify Authentication auth_service_unavailable

Tags: android, authentication, spotify, spotify-app

I am trying to login to spotify.
Although when the app is installed it always throws an AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE error. If the app is uninstalled the default Webview opens where the login works fine. Wished behaviour is, that the app opens and the user can login from there.

```
    public void doSpotifyLogin(boolean trySpotifyAgain) {
    this.trySpotifyAgain = trySpotifyAgain;
    AuthorizationRequest.Builder builder =
            new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(CLIENT_ID, AuthorizationResponse.Type.TOKEN, REDIRECT_URI);
    builder.setScopes(new String[]{"user-read-private", "streaming", "playlist-read-private", "user-library-read"});
    AuthorizationRequest request = builder.build();

    AuthorizationClient.openLoginActivity(this, SPOTIFY_LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE, request);
}
```

This is the response I am getting from the API:

```
2021-12-22 11:36:29.802 5069-5069/? I/com.spotify.sdk.android.auth.LoginActivity: Spotify auth completing. The response is in EXTRA with key 'response'
2021-12-22 11:36:29.822 5069-5069/? D/StartActivity: Spotify error: AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
```

If you need any further information, please let me know! Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm getting the same "AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE" exception. Ironically, it worked without having anything changed for months before. Another app with Spotify authentication works fine and still authenticates.

Comment: Really strange. I know this has worked before too, but I haven't found a solution yet to fix it.

Comment: Spend quite some days on it. Still couldn't find a solution yet..

Comment: Me neither. Guess I'll have to use the web login for now...

Comment: I have just encountered this error. It turned out that I changed my app suffix before, re-added the fingerprint to the Spotify Developer Dashboard and it's working again.

Comment: I struggled with this and fixed it when I added the correct package name and fingerprint to the developer.spotify.com app settings. "AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE" is a horrible error name for this.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue got resolved after I added the ***SHA1*** key generated on a ***new*** mac to the Spotify app dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Ronze's comment worked for me.  I needed to update my app's package name on developer.spotify.com.

Comment: Nice. Turning a comment into a confirmed and clearly attributed answer is appreciated. You might want to include all the details of the comment (just because theoretically comments might get deleted at some point).

Answer (score 0):

My android package and SHA1 fingerprint were correct. I tried removing user-read-birthdate permission from the authentication request and it worked for me!